# What are the recurrence rates for posterior shoulder dislocation?

Tags: statistics, orthopedics, shoulder

I know many publication which report recurrence rates for anterior shoulder dislocations, but couldn't find any study that reports recurrence rates specifically for posterior shoulder dislocations. So, are there any statistics about this? Maybe even statistics which distinguishes age classes, gender, athletic background, degree of labrum damage, surgery or not, etc

Comment: Interesting. Can you change the title to a question? Like "What are the recurrence rates for posterior shoulder dislocation?" Also, can you add references to some of the publications you're writing about?